# Structure a site's contents with the section elements and headings

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html-heading

I already know there are numerous threads outside discussing the use of section elements - I already read a lot of them and so far I came to the following conclusion:

A <section> element should be used to wrap content which could be stored as an individual database record. (according to HTML5doctor) and that the heading should be *inside* the section element (although in a database I wouldn't store the heading in the same column as content...))

So far so good, I reorganized my website's structure and had it analyzed by http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/ - but surprisingly it kind of ignored my h1, h2, ... headings order (somewhere I read that special elements reset the headings or so..? :S) which kinda drives me mad.

By now I've got a structure like (skipping some div's for styling purpose):

```
<header>
    <section>
        h1 // title of my page --> h1
    </section>
    <section>
        <nav>...</nav>
    </section>
</header>
<div role="main"> // don't use section for your website's main content
    h2 // main content
    <section>
        h3 // main content's sub heading
    </section>
    <section>
        h4 // sub heading of main content's sub heading
            h5
            h5
    </section>
    <section>
        h3 // another main content's sub heading
    </section>
</div>
<aside>
    <section>
        h3 // about me
    </section>
</aside>
```

instead of the expected outline:

```
title of my page
    navigation
    main content
        main content's sub-headings, etc.
    about me
```

I got:

```
main content
    title of my page
    navigation
    main content's sub entries
    about me
```

of course I could wrap my headings in some section elements to reset this counter, but I would never store the entire main content as a single database entry - so this would be an unsemantic usage of a semantic element, which makes the whole work somewhat redundant.

Did I miss the point of the section element or the nested headings? Any proposals how to handle this behavior (which sounds great in theory, but in practice it seems to be behave in a strange way...)

EDIT: I decided to stick to the "use article on elements that could be a RSS item" rule, as it makes much more sense to me and went on to use a section element to keep the main content apart from the navigation etc. (as answered below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The section element**

I'm not sure if I agree with your section definition. From the HTML5 specification it says

> The section element represents a generic document or application section.

It goes on to say

> Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element.

So I think an article should be used in place of section if you are going to store something as an "individual database entry". See also [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/) good list of DOs and DON'Ts for the section element.

**Document outlining**

In terms of your document outline, it is difficult to tell what is going on as you have not included any closing tags. Can you post a complete, valid HTML example?

There is an excellent overview of outlining in HTML5 documents on the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) which I recommend you read. Taking your example and adding the closing tags where I think they should be, and based on this article, I would propose the HTML

```
<doctype html>
<header>
    <h1>title of my page</h1>
</header>
<nav>My Nav</nav>
<article id="main-content">
    <h2>main content</h2>
    <section>
        <h3>main content's sub heading</h3>
        <section>
            <h4>sub heading of main content's sub heading</h4>
            <section>
                <h5>a sub, sub heading of main content's sub heading</h5>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>another main content's sub heading</h3>
     </section>
</article>
<aside>
    <h3>about me</h3>
</aside>
```

This produces the outline

1. title of my page

   1. Untitled Section (This is the nav)
   2. main content

      1. main content's sub heading

         1. sub heading of main content's sub heading

            1. a sub, sub heading of main content's sub heading
   3. another main content's sub heading
   4. about me

Is this the outline you expected?

**Section headings**

Note you don't have to use `h1`, `h2`, `h3` etc., the HTML5 outline will work out what is a heading, a sub-headingetc based on the depth of nesting of your article or section. You could, if you wnated, use `h1` everywhere (although don't) and the outliner would still produce the above outline.

Comment: thx for recommending the DOs and DON'Ts of the section element and proposal, but in the article it is stated that neither the article nor the section element should be used to divide content from header/footer (recommendation: div, see first of the DON'Ts items), but the div doesn't reset the "heading counter" --> would article be a semantic solution? (sry if I annoy you, but at the moment the only question is the one about semantics, because I could already have reached my aim much easier only using divs ^^)